# Modification and projective bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety and $D$ be a codimension 1 sub variety. Let $E$ be a rank 2 vector bundle on $X$. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $D$ which is quotient of $E|_D$. Then consider $Ker(E,L)$. Is it true that $\mathbb{P}(E)\cong \mathbb{P}(Ker(E,L))$?

Comment: What you describe is an "elementary modification".  The associated projective bundles are typically isomorphic.  Consider the case when $X$ is a projective line, $D$ is a rational point, and $E$ is a trivial rank $2$ bundle.  Then $\text{Ker}(E,L)$ is the vector bundle whose sheaf of global sections is $\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus \mathcal{O}$.  Thus, the first projective bundle is the Hirzebruch surface $\Sigma_0$, yet the second projective bundle is $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: Typo correction: "The associated projective bundles are typically *NOT* isomorphic".  The rest of the comment gives an example where the projective bundles are *NOT* isomorphic.

Comment: . . . Also, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: actually  $\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)$ is also an elementary modification of $\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}$. But in this case the projective bundles are same. But thanks for the counterexample.

Comment: In general the two projective bundles are related by a flip and accidentally the result of the flip can be isomorphic to the original bundle. The point is that the natural rational map given by the elementary modification is _never_ and isomorphism and is resolved explicitly by a flip. As a  bit of shameless self-promotion - take a look at Apppendix A of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008010 where this is explained and where you can find the references to the classical papers of Tyurin and Maruyama who analyzed this in detail.